# Can I copy a directory from within a docker Image in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a simple java web application(not maven) from within my docker file by pulling code from my git server and creating a deployable war.In order to do so I have to copy the classes directory to my WEB-INF Folder .My classes directory is at **/usr/app_name/build/classes**(in the docker image) and I want to copy it to **/usr/app_name/WebContent/WEB-INF/** (within the same image).

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 AS buildserver
WORKDIR /usr/app_name
RUN git clone http://uname:pass@git_server_host:git_server_port/scm/tes/app_name.git /usr/app_name 

COPY /usr/app_name/build/classes /usr/app_name/WebContent/WEB-INF/
#***#Is there any way to perform above operation***

WORKDIR /usr/app_name/WebContent/WEB-INF/
RUN jar -cvf app_name.war *
FROM tomcat:latest
COPY --from=buildserver /usr/app_name/WebContent/WEB-INF/app_name.war .
EXPOSE 5060
```

Comment: Could you do what you need by just running a `cp` command? `RUN cp -r /usr/app_name/build/classes /usr/app_name/WebContent/WEB-INF/` to copy the contents to `/usr/app_name/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes`. I've not added this as an answer because I'm not 100% sure if this is what you mean so any more information you can give would be helpful.



If you want to copy the content to `/usr/app_name/WebContent/WEB-INF` directly you could use `RUN cp -r /usr/app_name/build/classes/* /usr/app_name/WebContent/WEB-INF/`.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse too @Mark. I tried the cp and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `COPY` command in docker only works for copying files from the docker host machine to the image being built. You can do what you need by just running a `cp` command in the image (or using `rsync` or some other tool if you have them installed in the container). An example of this would be:

```
RUN cp -r /usr/app_name/build/classes /usr/app_name/WebContent/WEB-INF/
```

to copy the contents to `/usr/app_name/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes`, or:

```
RUN cp -r /usr/app_name/build/classes/* /usr/app_name/WebContent/WEB-INF/
```

if you want to copy the content to /usr/app_name/WebContent/WEB-INF directly.